# processing.js loading external files

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I want to split my processing.js code into several files but I'm not sure how. I tried doing

```
<script type="application/processing" src="main.pjs">
```

to load my processing.js file "main.pjs" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.hyper-metrix.com/misc/Processing.AJAX.init.zip

Answer (score 3):

I know this has already been answered, but I thought I'd add some more explanation:

The problem with your initial approach is that the browser does not know what to do with a file of type "application/processing", so it is never even pulled from the server. The init() package that TML posted looks for these and pulls them by means of XHR.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize Processing with a canvas and a string of source in JS.

Processing(canvas, sourceString)

That string could come from anywhere outside the current file.

Answer (score 1):

Processing.js can run code from an external file like so...

```
<script src="processing.js"></script>
<canvas datasrc="yourSketch.pjs" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```